# API REST: How do I decouple this controller?

Tags: rest, api-design

I have two type of entities: User and Resume. So my instinct said me to write two controllers.

UserController endpoints:

```
/users 
/users/{id} 
/users/{id}/resumes
```

ResumeController endpoints:

```
/resumes
/resumes/{id}
/resumes/searchBy[?criteria={criteria}]
```

User has a reference to resume, so to create one I do a POST to `/users/{id}/resumes`. Otherwise a POST to `/resumes/{id_user}/` doesn't seems to be RESTful, isn't it?

Is it right to have these two controllers? although the first one has a reference of the service of the second controller:

```
class UserController {

    UserService userService;
    ResumeService resumeService;

}
```

Should I combine them?

Comment: Rest has nothing to do with implementation details. Neither with how your URIs looks like. From the client point of view, URIs are meaningless.

Comment: @Laiv I reformulated my question

Comment: Nobody can say what"s right or not. You are looking for approval. Why do you need strangers approving your decisions? The only answer I could give is that your design leaks on consistency. You said that resumes must be related to a user and here we have a ResumeService to skip such business rule :-)

Comment: @Laiv that was a typo. It is related but user referencing it and not otherwise: user -> resume

Comment: Does your design allow consumers to get access to the resume directly? **Should** consumers have access to the resumes directly? Or should they retrieve the user first and ask then the user? That's the question.

Comment: @Laiv exactly, consumers access to the resumes directly, and having to pay to get access to their user

Comment: @Laiv problem was to decouple ResumeService from UserController. See EdwinJackson and Jacob Hull responses

Comment: `Actually, this is what I want, decouple ResumeService from UserController (adding userId field to Resume entity as @EdwinJackson pointed), but I don't know if I should because of business logic`. IMO. You should not. Send resumes to /users/id/resumes. Because consumer needs to know about the user first, so to me, make sense to keep working with /user/id/whatever when I'm operating with a user data. Finally, *UserSerivce.getUserResumes(user);* makes much more sense (to me) than *ResumeService.getResumeByUserId()*. This last let open a window to skip your business rule user -> resume

Comment: I was going to change my implementation (referring to Jacob answer) and I immediately faced the same problem again: I could decouple ResumeService from UserController but then I pass the problem to the underlying layer (service) as I need to somehow access to the user entity to update his reference to the created resume. So I can't and should not decouple them. You right @Laiv

Answer (score 3):

The question I think you need to answer for yourself is: Should your `UserController` handle resume creation?

Which is more of a separation of concerns issue.

When it comes to deciding what to name the different behaviors of your API you should understand the concept of [The Uniform Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172600/rest-what-exactly-is-meant-by-uniform-interface). The basics can be understood (very loosely) as: `you should use a standards based approach when designing an API`. The link explains those standards quite well.

Here's my 2 cents. Assuming a `Content-Type: application/json` API

I would create a resume as a `POST` to `/resume` and require a json `body` object with a `userId` property. An error would be thrown if it wasn't provided and no action would be taken by the API.

`{
  ...
  "userId": 1234
  ... other resume stuff
}`

And for the response I would return the `ResumeId` which would be created in the database.

Ultimately, you know how your API should be consumed.

Comment: Separating out a resumes endpoint from the users endpoint will avoid problems down the road and allow each service to evolve independently, e.g. user data unrelated to resumes

Answer (score 1):

You could really model this either way. It seems pretty natural to me that `/users/{id}/resumes` would be used to [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) user resumes and that `/resumes` would be a query-only endpoint. Nothing says that the API and database have to map one-to-one. Especially for queries, I usually find I need multiple representations of the data. It is often even worth it to maintain a separate view / table / data store to support the special needs of queries. For example full text search.

Answer (score 1):

Note that these endpoints are equivalent:

```
/users/{id}/resumes
/resumes/searchBy?user_id={id}
```

Allowing you to separate the `ResumeService` from your `UserController`.

As you can see from the above, `/users/{id}/resumes` is actually a filter on the collection thus it makes more sense to post to the entire collection: `/resumes`.

Comment: Actually this is what I want, decouple ResumeService from UserController (adding userId field to Resume entity as @EdwinJackson pointed), but I dont know if I should because of business logic: think of resumes as a catalog, so "buying" a resume means getting the user personal information, which then can be contacted. So my initial idea was to not include on a resume any information that could directly identify the user. E.g: a "hacker" could get the user information if the resume has the user id. I still have a lot to learn and maybe I'm being too cautious.

Comment: The only information that is revealed is what you choose to reveal. All resumes have an owner so they all have a foreign key to a user. If you can buy resumes then you need to make the code for change of ownership.

The only way someone can use ONLY a user's id maliciously is if you have gaping security holes somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I guess I could protect /users of being used without authorization. I'm working with Spring Framework and I still have to take a look at Spring Security. In fact I could use userId field only for POSTs of resumes, without storing it to the entity.  Leaving it one-directional relationship (user -> resume) as I wanted.

Comment: Then it will be necessary to add: `/users/searchBy?resume_id={id}`

Comment: This might be useful for you then:

https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java